# Compiling raylib for html5/wasm

Tags: emscripten, raylib

I'm trying to compile raylib for html5, but I can't seem to run `make` properly. Running `make PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B` in `raylib/src` returns this:

```
emcc -c rcore.c -Wall -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -Werror=pointer-arith -fno-strict-aliasing -std=gnu99 -Os -I. -Iexternal/glfw/include -Iexternal/glfw/deps/mingw -DPLATFORM_WEB -DGRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_ES2
make: emcc: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:558: rcore.o] Error 127
```

However, running `emcc` works fine in the current shell (prints `no input files`), `sh` and `bash`, and works in different terminal emulators.
`$PATH` is (from zsh and alacritty, my primary shell and terminal emulator):

```
/home/user/emsdk:/home/user/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/home/user/emsdk/node/14.15.5_64bit/bin:/opt/devkitpro/tools/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: is it still relevant?

Comment: @AlexBender I figured out that part of the problem has something to do with the makefile, but after messing with it and not getting very far, I gave up

Comment: would you like to try again? there is a great Discord server managed by ray, the creator of raylib. Give it a shot, this world is fascinating!

Comment: @AlexBender maybe some other time, I did end up asking there a while ago but got no response

Comment: sorry to hear that. At least the readme describes what to do, I was able to get emscripten and build some examples

Comment: are you building on windows or unix? the problems in the makefile seem to only affect (at least majorly) unix (from what i can tell)

Comment: i've tried on ubuntu

Comment: odd, so am I, what did you do to get it to work?

Comment: indeed I had troubles, try to invoke `make` with -e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that emsdk is installed, following current (as at 8 Jan '22) documentation will not result in working examples. Build would be failed.

In order to build it on Ubuntu with `make --version GNU Make 4.2.1` you need to provide `-e` option to pass environment variables to `make`

Then, after build is finished -- start python http server in `examples` directory and navigate to that address in browser: `python3 -m http.server 9999`
open `http://localhost:9999` and select desired example.

Comment: I'm going to file an issue on the official Github repo for this to be added to the documentation. I'll link back to here for credit. Thanks for this.